# Visual Studio TeamExplorer disable project check-in

Tags: .net, visual-studio, team-explorer

I need to disable check-in operation for several projects in my solution. I need it to ensure myself from uploading changes to projects which I don't want to change. Is it possible with Team Explorer?

Comment: Why are you changing read only projects?

Comment: Err. I have mistake there. Projects are not read only, but i should not change them

Comment: I was specifically wondering why you are changing things which, by your own admission, you _should_ not.

Comment: I realy don't :-) I converted solution of VS2008 to VS2010. All projects are now in VS2010 format. I don't want to check-in 2 certain team-shared projects because they should be in VS2008 format

Comment: In that case, you should edit the files externally to VS. They will work the way you want them to, and VS won't know that they've changed, so it won't check them in.

Comment: I can elaborate, if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS only tracks changes that are made through Visual Studio. In your case, you need to edit the files locally, but without VS knowing. Unfortunately, this is difficult, because your converter is running in VS.

The steps would be

1. "Get" Entire Solution
2. Open solution in VS
3. run converter to 2010
4. Copy the relevant sln files to a local folder.
5. Undo pending changes on the files you don't want checked in.
6. Paste the modified files back.

Some risks associated with this. 
This is a huge pain if the SLN files get changed very often, because your local changes will be overwritten. This cannot be avoided however, because this problem would still exist if you had them 'checked out' the normal way. 
You will not be able to add/remove projects to the SLN because your VS version is wrong. you will need to get someone with vs 2008 to "Add..." the project, then you'll have to get latest on the SLN and run the conversion steps again.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you cant do one of the following:

- Work offline (IIRC you can selectively bind projects within a solution)
- Shelve changes
- Create a branch

Answer (score 0):

You could change permissions on the folders in TFS to remove checkin rights.

But this could be a rather large hammer, why not just revert any changes to do (accidentally) make?

Comment: Thank you Richard. I know about this. I need this on client side

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd create a branch.